# Read-only OAuth access to Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

**Question1:** Is there way to achieve free read-only access to Kibana?

**Question2:** Is there way to achieve free OAuth login to Kibana?

Already everyone who have link to my Kibana have all accesses too. What I need is give some users read-only access.

I use docker ELK stack from: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

I know that `X-Pack` have those features but it is paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best free tool you can use is probably https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard but free version offers only basic auth.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, search-guard plugin seems to have everythink what I need.